# Difference between "to" and "to the"

Tags: grammar

I want to apply for a job in US in one or two years and now I'm trying to learn English grammar. I remember that I read sometime in a book the following sentences:

"I'm going home", "I'm going to school", "I'm going to the airport".

Could you explain me please when I should use "to", "to the" or no one of these, there also was explained that "the" is never used with home or school.

Also, please correct me if I made mistakes somewhere in the above text.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). This question might be a little too basic for this website, but we have a sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) where I think you might find an answer, just please make sure to have a look at the help centre there before posting, and search the site to see if someone has already asked a similar question. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I know it's basic :) first I tried to find an answer on google but I couldn't find one, but all answers from other questions come from here. Anyway thank you!:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, mistakes. Get that out of the way:

Could you explain me please when I should use "to", "to the" or **no one** of these, there also was explained that "the" is never used with home or school.

1. Explain **to me**...
2. Should use **neither of**, if two choices or **none of**, if more than two.

Okay, now the question. It's a good one.

Where using a word to refer to a class or category of place, like school or home, you don't use the article.

"I go to school five days a week." "When I go home, I pass by the airport."

When referring to a specific building, the article is used.

"Can you tell me where the school is?"

Also, titles of institutions often contain articles and these should be used when referring to them.

"I studied at The London School of Economics."

Home is almost always used generally, but there are exceptions.

"The dog was sent to a home for stray animals." "He comes from a good home." "Canada is the home of cajun cooking."

Airport is always used with an article.

"Take me to the airport."

Airport is never used to refer to a class or category. You wouldn't say,

"When in airport, never leave baggage unattended"

but you could say,

"He went to school to be an air traffic controller"

"Don't leave your passport at home when you go to the airport."

Comment: I was just reading the endless threads about that very topic! I considered using it as an example, but thought it would be too confusing. While the Brits have strict rules about these things, I still prefer, should the need arise, to go to the hospital, generally speaking. I'll decide on which one at the proper time.